# Finding Average based on more than one variable

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to find the average amount spent by accounts which have been used at least once in 2012 for each payment type in each month of 2012. The tables I am using have Transactions: account_id, purchase_date, payment_type and amount
Games: account_id, game_id and game_date

So far I have

```
 SELECT SUM(amount) FROM Transactions
 WHERE DATE (purchase_date) BETWEEN '2012-01-01' AND '2012-12-31'
 AND account_id in (SELECT account_id FROM Games WHERE (Games.game_date) 
 BETWEEN '2012-01-01' AND '2012-12-31') GROUP BY payment_type;
```

I am at a loss as to how to move this further along. The results I have so far only show one column so I don't even know which amount is for which payment type. How can I show the payment types beside these and then average them based on the number of transactions made per month?

EDIT

So I have

```
 SELECT payment_type, AVG(amount) FROM Transactions
 WHERE DATE (purchase_date) BETWEEN '2012-01-01' AND '2012-12-31'
 AND account_id in (SELECT account_id FROM Games WHERE (Games.game_date) 
 BETWEEN '2012-01-01' AND '2012-12-31') GROUP BY payment_type;
```

which shows me the average spent per payment method across 2012, I only need to sort this by the month now.

Comment: Simple. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have the sum for payment_type (using you query as table)

```
   select avg(tot)  from (
      SELECT payment_type, SUM(amount)  as tot FROM Transactions
       WHERE DATE (purchase_date) BETWEEN '2012-01-01' AND '2012-12-31'
       AND account_id in (SELECT account_id FROM Games WHERE (Games.game_date) 
       BETWEEN '2012-01-01' AND '2012-12-31') GROUP BY payment_type
   ) t
```

OR could be you need  only

```
 SELECT payment_type, SUM(amount), AVG(amount)   
 FROM Transactions
 WHERE DATE (purchase_date) BETWEEN '2012-01-01' AND '2012-12-31'
 AND account_id in (SELECT account_id FROM Games WHERE (Games.game_date) 
      BETWEEN '2012-01-01' AND '2012-12-31') 
 GROUP BY payment_type
```

Comment: The problem here is that this divides the total amount spent which is 880 by 4 (number of payment types) giving 220. What I am trying to find is the average per payment type.

Comment: I have update the answer .. hope is useful otherwise update your question add a proper data sample and the expected  result

Comment: Thankyou for your help again scaisEdge, i must have updated my question just before you replied again, I am happy enough now to move forward with this, ty